# How can we get a free flutter demo app from openCart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new here to use `openCart` in my mobile App using Flutter.

Can we get a free flutter demo app from `openCart`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenCart's frontend is only a webpage, instead of an app. Looking at its "download" page (https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/download) we can see that. Moreover, from its official code repository (https://github.com/opencart/opencart), we can see the languages as following:

[image]

Therefore, we double-confirmed that, its frontend is a webpage (and backend is php - though unrelated to the question). It also does not have any other repo such as mobile app or Flutter (see https://github.com/orgs/opencart/repositories).

In short, no. There simply does not exist any flutter demo app from opencart.

Comment: Thanks for response, My search is over with your answer.. Thank you

Comment: @GHPrakash You are welcome! You can also [award the bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).